# Using 'rel=canonical' with WordPress sub-categories to their parent category?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, categories

In case of a blog with 3-4 main categories and each of them have 3-4 sub-categories. To avoid duplicate content should the child categories use rel=canonical to their parent category?

Answer (score 1):

Neither, just use canonicals on the posts and pages. That way categories and author pages are never duplicate, but even without canonical Google has the ability to establish what is what. I recommend you install something like Yoast SEO. I also recommend you get more familiar with [canonical links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).